# Сложности в понимании того, как Stopwatch измеряет время в асинхронном коде

Tags: c#, асинхронность, async-await

Есть два варианта кода, в которых Stopwatch измеряет прошедшее время по разному. Я не могу понять почему. Вот этот код -

**1. Первый пример (в методе AsyncAction сначала идет синхронная часть, а затем - асинхронная) -**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DifferentTasks
{
    public class SyncAndAsyncPartsOfMethod
    {
        public async Task Execute()
        {
            IEnumerable<int> data = Enumerable.Range(0, 100);

            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            Task t = Task.WhenAll(data.Select(AsyncAction));
            await t;
            stopwatch.Stop();

            double elapsedSeconds = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds).TotalSeconds;

            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed seconds overall - " + elapsedSeconds);
        }
        
        private async Task AsyncAction(int x)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); 
            
            stopwatch.Stop();
                
            double elapsedSeconds = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds).TotalSeconds;
                
            Console.WriteLine($"AsyncAction {x} is finished, elapsed seconds - {elapsedSeconds}, thread - {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод:
Elapsed seconds overall - 102 seconds

Stopwatch в методе AsyncAction показывает, что каждый раз метод выполнялся ровно две секунды:

```
AsyncAction 95 is finished, elapsed seconds - 2,046, thread - 5
AsyncAction 96 is finished, elapsed seconds - 2,032, thread - 4
AsyncAction 97 is finished, elapsed seconds - 2,015, thread - 4
AsyncAction 98 is finished, elapsed seconds - 2,029, thread - 4
AsyncAction 99 is finished, elapsed seconds - 2,046, thread - 5
```

**2. Второй пример (в методе AsyncAction сначала идет асинхронная часть, а затем синхронная) -**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DifferentTasks
{
    public class SyncAndAsyncPartsOfMethod
    {
        public async Task Execute()
        {
            IEnumerable<int> data = Enumerable.Range(0, 100);

            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            Task t = Task.WhenAll(data.Select(AsyncAction));
            await t;
            stopwatch.Stop();

            double elapsedSeconds = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds).TotalSeconds;

            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed seconds overall - " + elapsedSeconds);
        }
        
        private async Task AsyncAction(int x)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); 
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            
            stopwatch.Stop();
                
            double elapsedSeconds = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds).TotalSeconds;
                
            Console.WriteLine($"AsyncAction {x} is finished, elapsed seconds - {elapsedSeconds}, thread - {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод:
Elapsed seconds overall - 13 seconds

Stopwatch в методе AsyncAction теперь показывает, что с каждым разом исполнение метода AsyncAction занимает все больше времени -

```
AsyncAction 92 is finished, elapsed seconds - 3,066, thread - 6
AsyncAction 89 is finished, elapsed seconds - 4,035, thread - 8
AsyncAction 87 is finished, elapsed seconds - 4,082, thread - 6
AsyncAction 85 is finished, elapsed seconds - 4,082, thread - 5
AsyncAction 83 is finished, elapsed seconds - 5,051, thread - 8
AsyncAction 81 is finished, elapsed seconds - 5,067, thread - 4
```

Code to start these class -

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DifferentTasks
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SyncAndAsyncPartsOfMethod syncAndAsyncPartsOfMethod = new();
            syncAndAsyncPartsOfMethod.Execute().Wait();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Хотелось бы понять почему -

1. Общее прошедшее время настолько сильно отличается в зависимости от того, исполняется ли сначала асинхронная часть, или синхронная
2. Почему в случае когда сначала выполняется асинхронная часть - время выполнения метода каждый раз увеличивается.

Comment: Начнём с того, что `Stopwatch` не является потокобезопасным. Раньше была такая информация в документации, сейчас её почему-то нет.

Comment: После `await Task.Delay` выполнение может продолжиться в другом потоке (без указания `ConfigureAwait(true)`)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov по поводу того что выполнение может продолжиться в другом потоке я знаю, но я не вижу как это может влиять?

Comment: Это влияет в том смысле, что Thread.Sleep будет блокировать либо основной поток приложения, либо пачку фоновых потоков, в зависимости стоит он до await или после.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, вроде бы здесь не должно быть проблем с использованием _Stopwatch_, т.к. нет _одновременного_ доступа к созданному экземпляру из разных потоков. Вообще, насколько помню, _Stopwatch_ ограниченно потокобезопасен. Например, если созданному экземпляру не делать Restart/Stop/Reset, то можно не опасаясь вызывать Elapsed из разных потоков одновременно.

Comment: @i-one а откуда информация про отсутствие потокобезопасности? Я не могу найти почему-то

Comment: Достаточно [код Stopwatch](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Diagnostics/Stopwatch.cs) посмотреть. Никакими блокировками он не защищён. Методы Start/Stop/Reset/Restart меняют состояние экземпляра, а IsRunning/ElapsedXXXX только читают состояние.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Попробую пояснить на пальцах.

Перед переходом к коду, нужно понять следующее:

1. Операция `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));` блокирует текущий поток. То есть этот поток ничего не может делать, пока эта операция не кончится.
2. Операция `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));` не блокирует ничего. Она может начаться в одном потоке, но продолжение (всё, что после этой строчки) будет выполняться в другом потоке.

Теперь смотрим на код. Допустим, что вы вызваете его в потоке А. То есть сама программа запускается в потоке А, вот это `Task t = Task.WhenAll(data.Select(AsyncAction));` вызывается в потоке A, и соответственно всё, что до await в методе `AsyncAction` тоже вызывается в потоке А.

Вот ваш метод, давайте развебемся что тут происходит:

```cs
private async Task AsyncAction(int x)
{
    // Вот метод начинается в потоке А
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();             
    
    // А вот тут вы блокируете поток А на 1 секунду. 
    // Это синхронное ожидание в потоке А. То есть все остальные AsyncAction 
    // не запущены и не могут быть запущены в данный момент, 
    // поскольку главный поток вашего приложения заблочен. 
    // Поскольку вы этот метод запускаете 100 раз, 
    // то поток А последовательно заблочен 100 раз на секунду, 
    // что дает 100 секунд ожидания. 
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    // Тут, спустя секунду, вы запускаете асмнхронное ожидание. 
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));                  

    // Спустя еще секунду мы окажемся здесь, при этом этот поток уже не А, 
    // а какой то другой. Мало того, поток А сейчас занят очередным синхронным ожиданием. 
    // Поскольку какой то другой поток (не А) будет запускать этот код, 
    // нет никаких проблем, чтобы асинхронно ожидалась именно секунда. 
    // Никто не блочит остальные потоки, а значит конец асинхронного ожидания 
    // будет отбработан быстро, 
    // потому в этом варианте у вас выводятся 2 секунды на каждое AsyncAction 
    stopwatch.Stop();
    double elapsedSeconds = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds).TotalSeconds;
    Console.WriteLine($"AsyncAction {x} is finished, elapsed seconds - {elapsedSeconds}, thread - {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
}
```

А теперь глянем на другой вариант

```cs
private async Task AsyncAction(int x)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();             
    // здесь мы запускаем асинхронную операцию в потоке А
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    // А вот все, что ниже этой строчки, будет выполнено уже не потоком А, а кем то другим. 
    // Поскольку `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));`, 
    // как асинхронная операция, не блокирует ничего, 
    // а метод AsyncAction вызывается 100 раз, 
    // то мы имеем 100 одновременно запущенных асинхронных операций. 
    // А значит, что нас ждет попытка запустить 100 продолженний одновременно. 
    // Но потоков в пуле то у нас не 100, а значит, 
    // что какие то продолжения начнут выполняться, 
    // заблочат все потоки в пуле потоков, и пока они не отвиснут, 
    // никакие другие продолжения не начнутся. 

    // Услвно говоря, если у нас всего 3 потока в пуле потоков (B, C, D), 
    // а продолжений у нас 100, 
    // то первые три продолжения заблочат все потоки B,C,D 
    // и остальные 97 продолжений просто ждут своей очереди.     
    // Но поскольку `Thread.Sleep` будет раскидан по разным потокам, 
    // то общее время ожидания будет меньше, чем в первом варианте. 
    // Условно, если в пуле потоков 3 потока, 
    // то общее время блокировки будет примерно 100/3+1 = 34 секунды. 
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));      

    stopwatch.Stop();
    double elapsedSeconds = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds).TotalSeconds;
    Console.WriteLine($"AsyncAction {x} is finished, elapsed seconds - {elapsedSeconds}, thread - {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
}
```

Чтобы понять связь с пулом потоков, можете в самом начале своей программы указать нужное вам количество потоков, например это

```cs
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(100, 100);
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);
```

Позволит второму варианту выполниться на 2 секунды, но не повлияет на первый вариант ничем.

Если проводить аналогии:

допустим, есть 100 человек, и каждому надо купить лекарство в аптеке.

В первом случае, все 100 челов идут в одну очередь, сидят к одному терапевту, кто выписывает лекарства (главный поток А), а после расходятся по аптекам (потокам в пуле). То есть если терапевт тратит на одного чела 1 секунду, то он потратит 100 секунд на всю очередь. Но вот он выписал рецепт первому в очереди, и пригласил второго, пока терапевт второму выписывает, первый идет в аптеку и покупает что надо. К моменту, когда второй выходит от врача, первый уже купил себе лекарство. Ну и так далее. Получается, когда 100й выходит от врача, все предыдущие уже купили лекарства, и 100й тратит 1 секунду чтобы и себе купить. И вуаля, общее время для всех ну где то 101 секунда.

Во втором случае, 100 пациентов одновременно заходят на госуслуги, выписывают себе рецепты сами (за 1 секунду) и толпой идут в разные аптеки города (одна аптека - один поток из пула). И в каждой аптеке будет своя очередь. Если всего 3 аптеки в городе, а пациентов 100, то будет примерно по 33 чела в очереди в каждую аптеку. Соответвенно, кому то повезет и он потратит 1 сек на госуслугах и еще 1 в очереди в аптеку. А кому то не очень, он потратит 1 сек на госуслугах, но простоит 33 сек в аптеке в очереди. Но зато в итоге, за примерно 35 секунд, все 100 пациентов будут с лекарствами.

Comment: Отличный ответ, спасибо большое.